# How to return a 2d array of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I've created a function and want this function to return a 2d array of pointers.
However I've tried a lot of methods and the compiler just gave me errors.
Here's my function, `cell` is a class I defined. For now I just give the function void type.

```
 void CreatePuzzle (int nRows, int nColumns, int minVal, int maxVal)
{
    //initialize the puzzle
    cell *Puzzle[nRows][nColumns];

    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
         for(int j=0; j < nColumns; j++)
         {
            Puzzle[i][j] = new cell(i,j);

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You can't return arrays from functions. 2. Variable-length arrays are a non-standard C++ extension. Solution: Make `Puzzle` a two-dimensional vector and return that type.

Comment: out of curiosity: returning a pointer to 2d array of pointers to cell, i.e. cell*** is not an option?

Comment: It's an abomination is what it is. Use the modern-day resources the language provides, like std::vector.

Comment: AB_: Not if you assign it to Puzzle, as the scope of Puzzle gets out of scope at the end of the function. Unless Puzzle is declared static. But using the standard C++ datatypes is just so much better in so many ways (memory management, multithread safe, standard i/o, etc).

Comment: @AB: `cell***` is a _terrible_ idea!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  just wanted to confirm that you can return arrays from function (though you shouldn't)

Comment: Isn't  *variable lenght array* is the C term, and  *an array of runtime bound* are standard C++ (8.3.4/1 and 8.3.4/4) - although poorly supported by mainsream compilers ?

Comment: @AB_: No you can't. You can return pointers to arrays.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, that's it

Comment: @Christophe: I don't know which C++ you're quoting but "of runtime bound" does not appear in the text of C++03, C++11 or C++14 (are you confusing it with "array of unknown bound", which is something else?) The term is Variable-Length Array and it's very well supported across all major compilers.

Comment: I refer to C++11 (more precisely N3690), "array of runtime bound" is explained in 8.3.4/1 on page 184 and an exampleon top op page 185.

Comment: @Christophe: n3690 is not C++11; it is a _working draft_ (NOT a standard!) from 2013. The text did not make it into final C++14, either, because [it was moved out of C++14 in the October 2013 working group meeting](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/the_view_form_the_c_standard_meeting_september_2013_part_1?lang=en). Be very careful when citing mere drafts.

Comment: Thank you all! Modern c++ woks. I'll avoid using c style arrays. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it may be helpful: consider using modern C++.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                       
#include <vector>                                                                                         

class Cell {                                                                                              
 public:                                                                                                  
  Cell(int value = 0)                                                                                     
      : m_value(value) { }                                                                                
  int value() const {                                                                                     
    return m_value;                                                                                       
  }                                                                                                       
  void value(int value) {                                                                                 
    m_value = value;                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                       
 private:                                                                                                 
  int m_value;                                                                                            
};                                                                                                        

class Puzzle {                                                                                            
 public:                                                                                                  
  Puzzle(int rows, int cols)                                                                              
      : m_cells(rows * cols),                                                                             
        m_rows(rows),                                                                                     
        m_cols(cols) {                                                                                    
    // for now let's assume we just give them a sequential value                                          
    int value = 0;                                                                                        
    for(auto & cell : m_cells) {                                                                          
      cell.value(value++);                                                                                
    }                                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                       

  Cell& cell(int row, int col) {                                                                          
    return m_cells[row * m_cols + col];                                                                   
  }                                                                                                       

 private:                                                                                                 

  std::vector<Cell> m_cells;                                                                              
  int m_rows;                                                                                             
  int m_cols;                                                                                             
};                                                                                                        

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {                                                                        
  if(argc != 3) {                                                                                         
    std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " rows cols" << std::endl;                                       
    return 1;                                                                                             
  }                                                                                                       

  int rows = std::stoi(argv[1]);                                                                          
  int cols = std::stoi(argv[2]);                                                                          

  Puzzle puzzle(rows, cols);                                                                              

  for(int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {                                                                   
    for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {                                                                 
      std::cout << puzzle.cell(row, col).value() << " ";                                                  
    }                                                                                                     
    std::cout << std::endl;                                                                               
  }                                                                                                       
}
```

It is an over-simplification, but you (hopefully) get the idea: I have a Cell class whose only purpose is to hold a value (in this case an integer). Then I create a game which consists of N-by-M cells.

The constructor of the game declares this explicitly: *to create a game, I need you to provide me the number of rows and columns". Internally, it places all the cells in a `std::vector`, and offers a public method to access that linear arrangement in a (row, column) manner. You simply "stride" the array yourself.

Hopefully it serves to show you a glimpse of how could a more idiomatic C++ looks like. It is not perfect code by any means, but it is a start.

I compiled the code using GCC 4.8.1 on OS X 10.7.4:

```
g++ game.cpp -std=c++11
```

A sample session:

```
./a.out 3 5
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

another session:

```
./a.out 2 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Notice that I never had to worry about allocation/deallocation or memory leaks: it is all managed by the `std::vector`.

Comment: That's a nice solution with a modern C++ design. Much easier to manipulate than a C style array of arrays of pointers that would be required for returning a pointer to a 2d array.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've adopted modern c++ in my code already and it works! ; )

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative with a 2d vector:

```
vector<vector<cell>> CreatePuzzle(int nRows, int nColumns, int minVal, int maxVal)
{
    //initialize the puzzle
    vector<vector<cell>> Puzzle(nRows, vector<cell>(nColumns));

    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++)
        {
            Puzzle[i][j] = cell (i,j);
        }
    }
    return Puzzle; 
}
```